# Which other "photo booth" program can I use besides cheese (on a Toshiba AC100)?

Tags: software-recommendation, webcam, arm, cheese, ac100

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba AC100 several days ago, as described at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/TEGRA/AC100, and seeing during the installation that the OS was able to use the camera (the installer suggested to make a photo for the first user), I wanted to play with the camera.

I couldn't understand how to find a "photo booth" program in the new-style menu+desktop (not the classical menu with sections), so I remembered the popular "cheese" Linux program, and installed it via the Software Update tool (or whatever it is called; can be invoked from the panel on the desktop).

But cheese doesn't start, i.e., it crashes. (The [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cheese/+bug/1013858) telling the same.)

As I said, the camera could be used by the OS on this machine -- this could be seen in the installer.

Which "photo booth" programs can be installed and used without crashes in Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba AC100 in order to play with the webcamera?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [guvcview](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guvcview) and check the [other](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=webcam&op=) software.